# How to remove names from list in all clients in Client/Server chat program

Tags: java

I am working on Client/Server chat and am having issues removing the name from the list on all the open clients when one client disconnects. Right I have it where it seems like it broadcasting the list between the clients but its not removing any of the name. Any help would be awesome. This project is worth 50% of my final grade.

Chat Server Code:

```
 class ChatHandler extends Thread
    {  public ChatHandler(Socket i, ArrayList<ChatHandler> h) 
     { 
        incoming = i;
        handlers = h;
        handlers.add(this);

        try{
            in = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println("Could not create streams.");
        }
     }
     public synchronized void broadcast(){

        ChatHandler left = null;
        for(ChatHandler handler : handlers){
            ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage();
            cm.setMessage(myObject.getMessage());
            cm.setName(myObject.getName());


            try{
                handler.out.writeObject(cm);

                System.out.println("Writing to handler outputstream: " + cm.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                //one of the other handlers hung up
                left = handler; // remove that handler from the arraylist   
            }
        }
        handlers.remove(left);

        if(myObject.getMessage().equals("bye")){ // my client wants to leave
            done = true;    
            handlers.remove(this);
            System.out.println("Removed handler. Number of handlers: " + handlers.size());
        }
        System.out.println("Number of handlers: " + handlers.size());
     }

     public void run()
     {  
        try{    
            while(!done){
                myObject = (ChatMessage)in.readObject();
                System.out.println("Message read: " + myObject.getMessage());
                broadcast();
            }               
        } catch (IOException e){  
            if(e.getMessage().equals("Connection reset")){
                System.out.println("A client terminated its connection.");

            }else{
                System.out.println("Problem receiving: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
        }finally{
            handlers.remove(this);
        }
     }

Client Code:

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){


        //TF ACTION LISTENER
        if (ae.getSource()== tf){

            if (connected) {

                myObject = new ChatMessage();
                myObject.setMessage(tf.getText());
                myObject.setName(name);
                tf.setText("");
                try{
                    myOutputStream.reset();
                    myOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                    System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
                }
            }else{
                name = tf.getText();
                setName(name);
            }
        }

        //BUTTONS
        if (ae.getSource()== connect){
            connected = true;
            name = tf.getText();
            setName(name);

            try{                        

                scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                myObject = new ChatMessage();

                socketToServer = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4001);

                myOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socketToServer.getOutputStream());

                myInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socketToServer.getInputStream());
                start();    
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
                }

            name = tf.getText();
            setName(name);

            myObject = new ChatMessage();
            myObject.setMessage(getName() + " has connected");

            myObject.setName(name);
            tf.setText("");
            try{
                myOutputStream.reset();
                myOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }           


            disconnect.setEnabled(true);

        }
        if(ae.getSource()== disconnect){
            connected = false;

            myObject = new ChatMessage();
            myObject.setMessage(getName() + " has disconnected");
            myObject.setName(name);
            myObject.setRemoveName(Clientlist);

            tf.setText("");

            try{
                myOutputStream.reset();
                myOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
            /*
            String[] items = Clientlist.getItems();
            for (String s: items){
            if(s.equals(myObject.getName())){
                RemoveFrom = true; 
                }
            }

            if(RemoveFrom == true){
                Clientlist.remove(myObject.getName());
            }*/

            try{
                myObject.setRemoveName(Clientlist);
                socketToServer.close();
                myOutputStream.close();
                myInputStream.close();


            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }   

        }
      }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Listening for messages from server . . . ");
        try{
            while(!receivingdone){
                myObject = (ChatMessage)myInputStream.readObject();
                ta.append(myObject.getName() + ": " + myObject.getMessage() + "\n");

                String[] items = Clientlist.getItems();
                boolean inList = false;
                for (String s : items){
                    if (s.equals(myObject.getName())) 
            { inList = true; }
                }
                if (inList == false) {
                    Clientlist.add(myObject.getName());
                }

        if (connected == false){
            for (String s: items){
                if(s.equals(myObject.getName())){
                RemoveFrom = true; 
                    }   
            }

            if(RemoveFrom == true){
                Clientlist.remove(myObject.getName());
            }
        }
            }

    }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("IOE: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
            System.out.println(cnf.getMessage());
        }

    }

Chat Message Code:
    import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ChatMessage implements Serializable{
    public String name;
    public String message;
    public List list;


    public ChatMessage(){}
    public ChatMessage(String name, String message){
        setName(name);
        setMessage(message);
        setRemoveName(list);

    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    public void setRemoveName(List list){
        list.remove(getName());
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List getRemoveName(){
        return list;    
      } 
    }
```

Comment: seriously you need us to download and read the whole code.

Comment: There  I fixed it.

Comment: The while(!done) and while(!receivingdone) code looks like placeholders for other code. Without seeing that other code I cannot tell if your code terminates its loops correctly. If it doesn't terminate a loop correctly it looks like the remove code may never be called.

Comment: The while(!done) and while(!receivingdone) are not placeholders. they are actual variables

Comment: You'll have more luck with feedback if you show all your code and indent it correctly.